# Rails 3 passing a rails array to javascript function which uses a javascript array

Tags: javascript, arrays, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to pass a rails array to a javascript function.  The function will then use the array values in javascript so I need to keep it an array.

Here is how I am passing my array:

```
"graphit([<%=@mpg_values.join(",") %>])"
```

This produces this in the HTML

```
"graphit([#&lt;Mile:0x6ff0cf0&gt;,#&lt;Mile:0x6ff0c18&gt;,#&lt;Mile:0x6ff0b58&gt;])"
```

Which are not the values, they should be decimal numbers.  I assume this is because it is a reference to the array so that I why I am getting the messed up values.  If I do something like to_s I see the values but it has other stuff like the table and filed name in there as well.

Anybody know how I can get this rails array to a javascript function as an array?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Perhaps you can simply use `@mpg_values.to_json`?

Comment: @Ankit Soni when I use to_json I get this [{"mile":{"mpg":"17.156136063144"}},{"mile":{"mpg":"19.06539208592"}},{"mile":{"mpg":"18.471164309032"}}] so I get the extra mile and mpg like in to_s.  I suppose I can parse this out in javascript but I would think there would be a simpler method to doing this.

Comment: How about just calling `@mpg_values.inspect`? I think the format it returns is the same as a JS array.

Comment: @Ankit-Soni That seems to do the same thing as to_s gives me this.. [#<Mile mpg: #<BigDecimal:6ded698,'0.1715613606 3144E2',16(20)>>,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Going to JSON as suggested a couple times in this post always gave me something like this.

> [{"mile":{"date":"2011-05-20","mpg":"18.565887006952"}},{"mile":{"date":"2011-06-01","mpg":"18.471164309032"}}]

What I really wanted was just this...  [[2011-05-20, 18.56][2011-06-01, 18.47]]

So I handled it with a helper like so.

```
  def chart_values()
    @chart_values = '['
    @mpg_values.each do |m|
      @chart_values = @chart_values+'['+m.date.to_s+', '+m.mpg.round(2).to_s+'],'
    end
    @chart_values = @chart_values+']'
  end
```

Then passed chart_values() to the javascript.

Likely not the best solution but it gave me the desired values in the format I needed.

Comment: I needed to return a specific array as JSON as well. I refactored your method and posted an answer to help others.

Answer (score 81):

Since this still seems like an issue and nobody resolved it.  Here goes

```
var js_array = [<%= raw @object.to_json %>];
```

Comment: Thanks alot for this answer, I was looking for it all over!

Comment: In my case no need to add []. Rails will add it. So var js_array = <%= raw @object.to_json %>; is fine for me. It may help someone

Comment: That is the great solution

Answer (score 1):

### Use Ruby's `collect` Method.

A cleaner version of your solution, Xaxum, would be something like this:

```
def chart_values
  @mpg_values.collect do |mpg_value|
    [ mpg_value.date.to_s, mpg_value.mpg.round(2).to_f ]
  end
end
```

The `collect` method automatically generates an array of whatever the block results in, so you'll end up with something like this:

```
[ 
  [2011-05-20, 18.56], 
  [2011-06-01, 18.47]
]
```

I also changed the `mpg` value to use `to_f`, which provide a number instead of a string.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using HAML, you can just do this:

`var js_array = #{object};`

Answer (score 0):

[bokor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10489036/7573223)'s answer works, but causes some linter and IDE errors if you want the array to be saved to a `const`, instead of a `var` / `let`.

The following variation seems to work and be compliant with the linters and IDEs that I am using.

`const js_array = JSON.parse('<%= raw @object %>');`