# Basic JavaScript array from an array of ruby arrays containing floats

Tags: javascript, arrays, ruby-on-rails, google-maps

I am trying to make a basic heatmap using Google Maps API - https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/heatmaplayer

I have an array of arrays of map coordinates I am passing from my rails controller like so:

```
@coordinates = [[51.60382, 0.02785], [51.6038, 0.02785], [51.60401, 0.02799], [51.60389, 0.02789], [51.60389, 0.02789], [51.60389, 0.02789], [51.60389, 0.02789], [51.60389, 0.02789], [51.60385, 0.02785], [51.60385, 0.02785], [51.60386, 0.02785], [51.60386, 0.02785], [51.60387, 0.02783], [51.60387, 0.02781]]
```

For each of these arrays I want to create a Google maps LatLng JavaScript object like so:

```
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.782551, -122.445368),
```

I can get the array of coordinate arrays through to the view ok however am struggling to create an array of the objects that look like that above.

My most recent attempt:

```
   var coordinatesArray = <%= @coordinates %>;

      function getPoints() {
        function coordinatesArrayTwo () {
          var coordinatesArrayNew = coordinatesArray.map( c => new google.maps.LatLng(c[0], c[1]) );
          return coordinatesArrayNew;
        };

        return[coordinatesArrayTwo()]
```

The idea being to iterate through the array of arrays and create a new object inserting the array coordinates...

However this does not seem to work and I am having a hard time viewing what it is actually returning.

I have a feeling it is fairly basic but could anyone help with this?

Thanks

Comment: What's the error you're facing right now? Can you post the console errors at least to be able to understand your problem? this `var coordinatesArray = <%= @coordinates %>;` is suspicious.

Comment: `visualization_impl.js:formatted:277 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: b.lat is not a function`
Is the only error I get in the console. Apparently this is due to the array being in the wrong format... I have tried .to_json and .html_safe on that `@coordinates` array too...

Comment: I think you're looking for this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7195943/rails-3-passing-a-rails-array-to-javascript-function-which-uses-a-javascript-arr

Comment: Thanks but I have seen this... I do not think the ruby array itself is the issue rather the JavaScript code that iterates through and builds the new array of objects?

Comment: The javascript snippet in my answer works, so if you are having a problem I think it lies with your array conversion or google API implementation.

Comment: Thanks Pilchard I can see you are returning an array of coordinates but not creating the points like so `new google.maps.LatLng(37.782551, -122.445368)`?

The api implementation works when you hard code each `new google.maps.LatLng(37.782551, -122.445368)` in and the map displays fine, it is only when I try using this array...

Answer (score 0):

I think you have an issue right on this one: `var coordinatesArray = <%= @coordinates %>;`

I am suggesting to try this one. `JSON.parse('<%= @coordinates %>')`

or you have to try `raw` also, `JSON.parse('<%= raw @coordinates %>')`

```
var coordinatesArray = JSON.parse('<%= @coordinates %>')

// Sample below: from googleApi Docs.
var heatmapData = coordinatesArray.map( c => new google.maps.LatLng(c[0], c[1]) );
var sanFrancisco = new google.maps.LatLng(37.774546, -122.433523);

map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
  center: sanFrancisco,
  zoom: 13,
  mapTypeId: 'satellite'
});

var heatmap = new google.maps.visualization.HeatmapLayer({
  data: heatmapData
});
heatmap.setMap(map);
```

Comment: I have not been working on Rails last 2/3 years, i have had done this previously.

Also try those: `<%= @ coordinates.to_json %>` or `JSON.parse(<%= @ coordinates.to_json %>)`

Comment: Thanks 7urjm3n there were two issues with my initial code:

1) It required `.to_json` as per your response 
2) The `getPoints` function needed tweaking as per Raphael St's response...

Answer (score 0):

The solution borrows from both Raphael St & 7urkm3n repsonses...

1. I needed to `.to_json` the ruby array like so:

```
 var coordinatesArray = <%= @coordinates.to_json %>;
```

2. I needed to tweak the `getPoints` function like so:

```
   function getPoints() {
          var coordinatesArray = <%= @coordinates.to_json %>;
          return coordinatesArray.map( c => new google.maps.LatLng(c[0], c[1]) );
        };
```

This gives the following to produce the heatmap:

```
      let map, heatmap;

      function initMap() {
        function getPoints() {
          var coordinatesArray = <%= @coordinates.to_json %>;
          return coordinatesArray.map( c => new google.maps.LatLng(c[0], c[1]) );
        };

        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
          zoom: 13,
          center: {
            lat: 51.603,
            lng: 0.0232
          },
          mapTypeId: "satellite"
        });
        heatmap = new google.maps.visualization.HeatmapLayer({
          data: getPoints(),
          map: map
        });
      }

      function toggleHeatmap() {
        heatmap.setMap(heatmap.getMap() ? null : map);
      }

      function changeGradient() {
        const gradient = [
          "rgba(0, 255, 255, 0)",
          "rgba(0, 255, 255, 1)",
          "rgba(0, 191, 255, 1)",
          "rgba(0, 127, 255, 1)",
          "rgba(0, 63, 255, 1)",
          "rgba(0, 0, 255, 1)",
          "rgba(0, 0, 223, 1)",
          "rgba(0, 0, 191, 1)",
          "rgba(0, 0, 159, 1)",
          "rgba(0, 0, 127, 1)",
          "rgba(63, 0, 91, 1)",
          "rgba(127, 0, 63, 1)",
          "rgba(191, 0, 31, 1)",
          "rgba(255, 0, 0, 1)"
        ];
        heatmap.set("gradient", heatmap.get("gradient") ? null : gradient);
      }

      function changeRadius() {
        heatmap.set("radius", heatmap.get("radius") ? null : 20);
      }

      function changeOpacity() {
        heatmap.set("opacity", heatmap.get("opacity") ? null : 0.2);
      } // Heatmap data: 500 Points
```

And it works!

Thanks all for the help.

Answer (score -1):

I am not entirely sure if it is what you are asking for

```
function getPoints() {
   return coordinatesArray.map( c => new google.maps.LatLng(c[0], c[1]) );
  };
  new_array = getPoints()
```

Comment: Thanks Raphael - could I ask how you are inspecting the array to see what is being returned? Still getting the error `visualization_impl.js:11 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: b.lat is not a function`

Comment: Well I am not using a google map api key so i skipped the google api.

var coordinatesArray = [[51.60382, 0.02785], [51.6038, 0.02785], [51.60401, 0.02799], [51.60389, 0.02789], [51.60389, 0.02789], [51.60389, 0.02789], [51.60389, 0.02789], [51.60389, 0.02789], [51.60385, 0.02785], [51.60385, 0.02785], [51.60386, 0.02785], [51.60386, 0.02785], [51.60387, 0.02783], [51.60387, 0.02781]]; function getPoints() {
   return coordinatesArray.map( c => [c[0], c[1]] );
  };
  new_array = getPoints(); console.log(new_array)    //This will output your table